# Iterator stack hasNext() not returning true

Tags: java, arrays, object, interface, iterator

I'm trying to iterate over an Object array. Using the next() method works so I'm guessing that my iterator class and constructors are working.

For some reason i'm not getting any output while the hasNext() method is running.

```
        Iterator it = hej.iterator();
    Object j = it.next();
    System.out.println(j);


    while(it.hasNext()){
        Object i = it.next();
        System.out.println(i + " ");
    }
```

With "hej" being my Object array.

My code for the next(); and hasNext() methods are as follows:

```
public class StackIterator implements Iterator<Object>{

// fields
private int element = 0;
private final Object[] elements;
private final int max;

// constructor

public StackIterator(Object[] values, int maxIndex) {
    elements = values;
    max = maxIndex;
}

// methods
public boolean hasNext() {
    return element < max;
}

public Object next() {
    return elements[element++];
}
```

}

The file that constructs the Object Array and the Object Array depends on an interface:

```
public interface Stack {
int size();
boolean isEmpty();
void push(Object element);
Object pop();

Object peek();

Iterator<Object> iterator();
```

}

The methods are then explained in another file:

```
public class StackExample implements Stack {

// fields
int length = 0;
Object[] arr;

// constructor
public StackExample() {arr = new Object[length];}


// method returns size of object array
public int size() {
    return arr.length;

}

// method checks if object is empty
public boolean isEmpty() {
    boolean result = false;
    if (arr.length == 0){
        result = true;

    }
    return result;
}

// method for push
public void push(Object element) {
    newBiggerObj();
    arr[0] = element;
}

// returns the first object of the stack
public Object pop() {
    Object[] temp = new Object[arr.length-1];
    Object first = arr[0];
    for (int i = 0; i<arr.length-1; i++){
        temp[i] = arr[i+1];
    }arr = temp;
    return first;
}

// returns the object on top of stack
public Object peek() {
if (isEmpty()){
    try{
        throw new Exception("Stack empty, can't peek!");
    }
    catch(Exception e){
        return e.getMessage();
    }
}

else {
    Object first = arr[0];
    return first;
}

}

// method for push method
private void newBiggerObj(){
    Object[] temp = new Object[arr.length+1];
    for (int i = 0; i<arr.length; i++){
        temp[i+1] = arr[i];
    }
    arr = temp;
}

public String toString(){
    String str = "";
    for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++){
        str = str + arr[i] + " , ";
    }return str;
}

public Iterator<Object> iterator() {
    return new StackIterator(arr, length);
}
```

}

What bothers me is that the method Iterator is within itself returning an instance of the class Stack Iterator. Which i posted above. So my real problem seems to be that my fields are not being given any value, since I am not myself giving the any values within the constructor.

My main method in which I'm testing all of this is as follows:

```
public class Teststack {
public static void main(String[] args){
    // new instane of class StackExample
    StackExample hej = new StackExample();

    // test for the different methods
    System.out.println(hej.isEmpty());
    System.out.println(hej.size());
    hej.push(4);
    hej.push("hej");
    hej.push(6);
    hej.push(5);
    System.out.println(hej.size());
    System.out.println(hej.peek());
    System.out.println(hej.pop());
    System.out.println(hej.toString());
    System.out.println(hej.isEmpty());


    System.out.println("Testing Iterator: ");
    // test for iterator
    Iterator it = hej.iterator();
    Object j = it.next();
    System.out.println(j);


    while(it.hasNext()){
        Object i = it.next();
        System.out.println(i + " ");
    }
}
```

}

Comment: So what maxIndex did you give when you constructed the iterator? Show more of the code.

Comment: Can you please show use the whole code of how you use `StackIterator`? What is `hej`? How many items does it have?

Comment: updated the question with all the files being used.

Comment: I would learn how to use a debugger.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is here:

```
public Iterator<Object> iterator() {
    return new StackIterator(arr, length);
}
```

`length` field is never changed, so its value is always `0`. You can change the code to this:

```
public Iterator<Object> iterator() {
    return new StackIterator(arr, arr.length);
}
```

Also, before retrieving elements from the iterator, you should always call `it.hasNext`. The fact you did this:

```
Iterator it = hej.iterator();
Object j = it.next();
```

And worked was just pure luck.

---

Apart of this, I can sense you have a bad design on your stack implementation. Here are some hints to improve your code:

- The inner array should be initialized with a default size different than 0. E.g. 10 (as done in `java.util.ArrayList` implementation).
- You should avoid creating a new array when adding (`push`) or removing (`pop`) an element from your stack. Instead of this, you should use the `length` field to control how many elements are in your `stack`.
- The value of the new size should be based on another formula rather than `array.length + 1`. For example, try using something like `int newSize = array.length / 2 * 3;`.
- Resize the inner array only when necessary. When calling `push`, do it only if you precisely need to increase the size of the array. When calling `pop`, do it if the current length of the array (this is, `array.length`) is far greater than the value of `length` field of your class.
- Never forget to update the value of `length` on `push` and `pop` methods.

Comment: YES. Thank you, was thinking that this had to be fix-able without changing all of the methods.

Comment: @user3428810 you're welcome. Please don't just fix your code, I strongly recommend you to read and implement the changes described in the bottom part of my updated answer. This will improve your implementation and, more importantly, your knowledge.

Comment: I will, just excited to not have to change three methods. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

In your `StackExample` class, I don't see the `length` variable being updated when elements are pushed or popped. Due to this, `length` will always be 0 and calls to `it.hasNext()` will always return false.

You don't need to pass the length as a separate argument. You can find the array's length in the `StackIterator` constructor and use it.

Also note that since you're creating a new array on every push and pop, the iterator returned by `StackExample#iterator()` will become stale after every push/pop since it will work on an old copy/state of the stack.

Comment: This is because OP's creating a new array called `temp` and storing elements there, then replacing `array` with `temp`.

Comment: So to avoid this problem i would have to change the methods that could be using the variable length? Is there any way to avoid this since that seems like a lot of coding.

Comment: @Luiggi But it also tracks `length` separately. Or, doesn't.

Comment: @DavidConrad it's supposed to do, but since OP always changes the inner array on `push` and `pop` methods, it is kind of futile to use `length` field. I have pointed all this in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Couple of issues:

- You are calling `Object j = it.next();` after creating iterator and then check for hasNext. You are incrementing the element index. Hence if you just have one element, you wont enter the while loop. In addition, if your custom datastructure is empty i.e. array has no elements then you are prone to ArrayIndexOutOfBoundException.
- You will always iterate and print n-1 elements instead to n elements.
- Once you iterated, then your pointer will always point to last element and never get resetted. So very next time you wont be able to iterate over your elements. Its a one time iterator.

Comment: Updated the question. The Object has a total of three elements when it is going into the while-loop. Or two if indeed the first element is incremented when calling next();.

Comment: OP understands all this, and based on the code of `main`, it seems more like a problem in `push` and `pop` methods rather than a problem in the iterator.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza am sorry it was pasted by OP and am not OP so i don't know what he/she know or don't.My answer was purely on what was pasted by OP before editing the question.

Comment: Before OP edited his/her question, the code of the iterator was posted, and there wasn't any of these problems there. That's why I downvoted this.

Comment: All Iterators are one-time Iterators. That is exactly how an Iterator is supposed to work.

Answer (score 0):

Try not to call
Object j = it.next() statement, but just while cycle. Seems you have an array of just 1 element.

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of problems with this code:

- In the `StackIterator` constructor there is no bounds checking on `maxIndex`. Callers can pass in a number greater than `values.length`, less that 0, etc.
- In the `next` method, there is no check of the end condition, either directly or by calling `hasNext()`. Callers can keep calling `next()` and see elements beyond `max` or even get an `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`, when they should be getting a `NoSuchElementException`.
- The `Stack` class never increments or decrements its `length` field when elements are pushed or popped.
- The `Stack` class tracks the `length` separately from the array, even though it always resizes the array on every push or pop, but Java arrays already know their size. (But see the next item.)
- The `Stack` class resizes the array on every push or pop, which is very inefficient. Typically classes like this only resize the array when necessary, allowing 'slack' space, to give amortized constant time performance (see ArrayList). If you do this, however, it is necessary to `null` out popped items to avoid unintentional object retention.
- The `Stack` adds and removes elements at the beginning of the array. This is incredibly inefficient since it means a O(n) reshuffling must be done on *every* push or pop.
- The `peek()` method takes into account the possibility that the `Stack` may be empty, but the `pop()` method does not. A `pop()` on an empty `Stack` will throw an `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`.
- `Stack` is not a generic class. It holds `Object`. Users of the `Stack` will have to cast the return values from `peek()` or `pop()`, and it isn't type safe. In your example, you show a stack that is a heterogeneous mixture of `String` and `Integer`. This is a very Java 1.2 way of doing things, and while it isn't necessarily wrong, you should consider parameterizing `Stack`.